# The link of a website

Tags: html

İ have created a search engine on html with the following code:

```
<form method="get" action="www.imisoundkarnaval.com">
   <table cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
      <tr>
         <td style="border-style:solid none solid solid;border-color:#4B7B9F;border-
            width:1px;">
            <input type="text" name="zoom_query" style="width:100px; border:0px solid; 
               height:17px; padding:0px 3px; position:relative;"> 
         </td>
         <td style="border-style:solid;border-color:#4B7B9F;border-width:1px;"> 
            <input type="submit" value="" style="border-style: none; background: 
               url('searchbutton3.gif') no-repeat; width: 24px; height: 20px;">
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

but for some reason it is not linked with the site i wanted the code to be!!

Can anybody help me by finding the true link of the following site = www.imisoundkarnaval.com

Or helping me with a better search engine?

Comment: update action as "http://www.imisoundkarnaval.com" means you need to add http:// with the URL in Action.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a *relative* URI, which will take you to `http://example.com/www.imisoundkarnaval.com`.

You need to start a URI with a scheme (`http://` or `https://`) to have an absolute URI or a double slash (`//`) to have a scheme relative URI if you want to link to a URI with a different hostname.

Answer (score -1):

For URl you will have to use `http://www.example.com` simple using `www.example.com` wont work as already explained by @Quentin. So try this and it should work out:

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.imisoundkarnaval.com"> 

<table cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px"> 

<tr> 

<td style="border-style:solid none solid solid;border-color:#4B7B9F;border-

width:1px;">

<input type="text" name="zoom_query" style="width:100px; border:0px solid; 

height:17px; padding:0px 3px; position:relative;"> 

</td>

<td style="border-style:solid;border-color:#4B7B9F;border-width:1px;"> 

<input type="submit" value="" style="border-style: none; background: 

url('searchbutton3.gif') no-repeat; width: 24px; height: 20px;">

</td>

</tr>

</table>

</form>
```

***Happy Coding!***